# Batch file "If" statement errors

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I seem to be having tons of trouble making this program.
I finally only have one more error. Here is my code:

```
:tutq
echo What is the first letter of your name?
echo 1(A
echo 2(B
echo 3(C
echo 4(D
echo 5(E
echo 6(F
echo 7(G
echo 8(H
echo 9(I
echo 10(J
echo 11(K
echo 12(L
echo 13(M
echo 14(N
echo 15(O
echo 16(P
echo 17(Q
echo 18(R
echo 19(S
echo 20(T
echo 21(U
echo 22(V
echo 23(W
echo 24(X
echo 25(Y
echo 26(Z
set /p tutnum=
If not defined !tutnum! (
cls
goto tutq
)
If "!tutnum!" == "1" (
set "tutlet=A"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "2" (
set "tutlet=B"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "3" (
set "tutlet=C"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "4" (
set "tutlet=D"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "5" (
set "tutnum=E"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "6" (
set "tutlet=F"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "7" (
set "tutlet=G"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "8" (
set "tutlet=H"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "9" (
set "tutlet=I"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "10" (
set "tutlet=J"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "11" (
set "tutlet=K"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "12" (
set "tutlet=L"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "13" (
set "tutlet=M"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "14" (
set "tutlet=N"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "15" (
set "tutlet=O"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "16" (
set "tutlet=P"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "17" (
set "tutlet=Q"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "18" (
set "tutlet=R"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "19" (
set "tutlet=S"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "20" (
set "tutlet=T"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "21" (
set "tutlet=U"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "22"(
set "tutlet=V"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "23" (
set "tutlet=W"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "24" (
set "tutlet=X"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "25" (
set "tutlet=Y"
goto tutp2
)
If "!tutnum!" == "26" (
set "tutlet=Z"
goto tutp2
)
:tutp2
echo Congrats!
echo If you did the exersize correct
 echo The first letter of your name should be "!tutlet!"
pause
```

Anyways if you could explain to me whats wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting? At an initial glance, I can see two possible problems with your code, but since what you've posted doesn't start with `@echo off`, I'm assuming this isn't the entire code.

Comment: @SomethingDark The full code has "@echo off" and "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" As for the error on getting it seems to do nothing at all with what I'm inputting. It just blinks and stays on the screen.

Comment: Next time please don't post your code elsewhere and link to it. Put it here in your question. You might draw downvotes for linking to it so editing your question and doing it now might be a good idea.

Comment: @Carey Gregory Thanks, I can't figure out how to do it without using the code button for each line though.

Comment: In the editor of your choice, insert 4 spaces in front of each line of your code and then copy/paste that here.

Comment: @Carey Gregory Thank you once more. I'm on mobile right now but I'll try my best.

Comment: Posting code to SO from a mobile device is a good way to make your life harder.

Comment: Please note that `DOS` is an Operating System from the 80s/90s! Please use the tag Windows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually doing exactly what you told it to, it's just going so fast you can't notice it.

When you are checking to see if a variable exists, don't wrap it in `%`s or `!`. `if not defined varname` essentially says, "if there is no variable called 'varname', then do this..."; when you surround it with `%` or `!`, you replace the variable with its value. If I entered `10` at the prompt, the code would be saying "If there is no variable called 10, then clear the screen and go back to tutq." Since there *is* no variable called 10, you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Change `If not defined !tutnum! (` to `If not defined tutnum (` and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You've accepted a good answer - please leave it that way. This is supplemental information that may prove useful, if not to you then to others facing the same problem.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "letequ=a(1 b(2 c(3 d(4 e(5"
:tutq
cls
FOR %%a IN (%letequ%) DO echo %%a
SET "tutnum="
SET /p "tutnum=What is the first letter of your name? "
IF NOT DEFINED tutnum GOTO tutq
FOR %%a IN (%letequ%) DO (
 SET letterandnumber=%%a
 SET "letter=!letterandnumber:~0,1!"
 SET "number=!letterandnumber:~2!"
 IF "!number!"=="%tutnum%" (
  ECHO The first letter of your name is "!letter!"&pause&GOTO :EOF)
)
GOTO tutq
```

So - I didn't bother to complete the letter/number set. It should be fairly obvious how to do that.

Note the technique of setting a string-value. That syntax ensures trailing spaces on a line are **not** included in the value assigned, which can sometimes cause problems. For instance,

```
SET tutnum=
```

should clear `tutnum` out of the environment which means that as far as `cmd` is concerned, it has a value of *nothing* **but** if there are stray (and conveniently invisible) spaces on the end of the line, it would be set to those spaces and `if defined tutnum` would be **true**.

```
SET "tutnum="
```

would clear `tutnum` as desired, stray spaces or no.

Setting a variable just before a `set /p` may seem superfluous, but if the response to a `set /p` is simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the variable will remain **unchanged** - it will not automatically have no value as may be assumed. This technique can be used to assign a default value

```
set "var=default"
set /p "var=prompt-string"
```

will leave `default` assigned to `var` if the user responds <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This could be used like

```
set "var=default"
set /p "var=prompt-string [%var%]"
```

To show the user the value that will be used if the user responds <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Next item to be examined is the `for` loops. `for` can be subject to all kinds of jiggery-pokery, but the basic for is

```
for %%x in (list of items separated by spaces) do something
```

where each item in the list in turn is assigned to `%%a`, so each item in the list `leteq` is assigned in turn to `%%a` and `%%a` adopts the values "a(1" "b(2" "c(3" "d(4" and  "e(5", then does *something* with that value.

In the case of the *analyse-the-entry* portion of the code, *something* is

```
 SET letterandnumber=%%a
 SET "letter=!letterandnumber:~0,1!"
 SET "number=!letterandnumber:~2!"
 IF "!number!"=="%tutnum%" (
  ECHO The first letter of your name is "!letter!"&pause&GOTO :EOF)
```

The object here is to *substring* the value in `%%a` example: "c(3". We can't do a direct substring of `%%a`, so we assign `%%a`'s value to `letterandnumber` and substring *that*.

The substring syntax is

```
%var:~m,n%
```

- If m is >=0, then the start of the substring is the m'th character of `var`, starting at "character 0"
- If m is <0, then the start of the substring is the m'th character from the **end** of `var`
- If n is >0, then `n` is the **length** of the substring
- If n is <0, then the end of the substring is the n'th character from the **end** of `var`
- n may be omitted. If omitted, the substring is "from the start position to the end"
- `%` may be `!` for `delayedexpansion` mode

So `letter` is set to `~0,1` that is, the first character for a length of 1 of `letterandnumber` and similarly `number` is set to `~2` - the third letter up to the end of the string.

Since `letterandnumber` is set *within* the loop (or in any parenthesised sequence of statements, aka "a block") then it may appear as two separate values. `%letterandnumber%` refers to the value *at the time the block is first encountered and parsed* whereas `!letterandnumber!` refers to the value *at run-time as it might be set within the block*. The `!var!` syntax is only valid if a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command has previously been executed.

The reason is that `cmd` replaces any `%var%` with the current value of `var`, then checks the statement for validity. `!var!` is not replaced until the block is *executed*.

The consequence of this sequence is significant and if not understood can lead to some vigorous head-scratching.

Suppose we have (note that close-parentheses ase used, not open)

```
SET "letequ=a)1 b)2 c)3"
FOR %%a IN (%letequ%) DO echo %%a
```

This will lead to a syntax error *because* `cmd` will first replace `leteq` with its then-current value and *then* parse it, so it sees

```
FOR %%a IN (a)1 b)2 c)3) DO echo %%a
```

assumes that the first close-parenthesis ends the list and expects a `do` but finds `1` so it reports the problem.

One way to solve this problem is to *escape* the misinterpreted <kbd>)</kbd> by preceding it with a caret <kbd>^</kbd>

```
SET "letequ=a^)1 b^)2 c^)3"
FOR %%a IN (%letequ%) DO echo %%a
```

`cmd` now sees `FOR %%a IN (a^)1 b^)2 c^)3) DO echo %%a` and recognises that `^)` means "this parenthesis is data, not part of the command" It's therefore happy with the syntax and proceeds to execute the code.

Another way is this (if delayedexpansion is in effect)

```
SET "letequ=a)1 b)2 c)3"
FOR %%a IN (!letequ!) DO echo %%a
```

`cmd` does not substitute the value until *after* the command has passed the validity check so no error is raised.